# Token authorization - Browser throws Login form

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, token

I am working on a token implementation into Angular/.Net application. My part is the front-end. What's happening is that when UI sends a request with the expired token and the server replies with 401 I cannot intercept that before the Browser raises the Login form. As the result I cannot send a request to refresh the token. Can someone please give me an idea how that is supposed be managed? I will provide code just don't know what's to show.

Thanks

Adding code:

```
var response = $http({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        params: params,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        },
        url: someurl
    });
    response = response.then(function (data) {
        return data.data;
    });
    response.catch(function (data) {
        $q.reject(data);
    });
    // Return the promise to the controller
    return response;
```

The problem is that I cannot redirect on UI because Browser throws Login form before my code is hit when the server returns 401.

Comment: If you can't tell when the token expired without sending an ajax request, there's likely nothing you can do from a client-side pov to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax request, and if you get 401 then redirect to login page.

P.s. for better understanding provide your code how you implement ajax request. Which module do you use for front-end auth? I recommend [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

**Added:**
I guess you need the following configuration on angular

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['satellizer'])

.config(function() {
    /* your config */
}

.run(function($rootScope, $location, $auth) {

    // Check auth status on each routing,
    // Redirect to login page, if user is not authenticated or if token expired
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            $location.path('/auth/login');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I cannot redirect. Browser shows its form before my code gets control.

Comment: I see. Will it get into that listener when data is requested without changing a route?

Comment: @Mark nope. and, i doubt it would get around the 401 causing the auth dialog either.

Comment: How then do we handle this situation?

Comment: @Mark, it's for routing. Also you can use ng-show to get your goal, define `$scope.requestCompleted = false;` in controller, and when your request completed and you get 401 just update `$scope.requestCompleted = true;` and use this var in your view to show or hide login form.

Comment: before vote me down have a look on the code!
by the way, I delete it!

Comment: @Rashad. I think you are missing the point. It does not reach Angular code. Browser shows Login form before. No way to redirect.

Comment: @Hitmands I downvoted because you dumped code on the page without explaining the purpose of it or what changed and why.